# Issue in vue.js with imported .scss

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I am currently reconstruct my vue app for a better overview over applied css/scss rules. I have the most parts inside components but want to make use of imported .scss files for specific rulesets.

**The problem which occurs is, that imported .scss files are handled like regular .css files.**

For example:

```
/* inside @/styles/_default.scss */
div {
  background-color: white;
  & span {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

The `<span>` Tag won't recive styling. In dev console it gets marked as invalid syntax.

However inside any .vue component it gets rendered just fine. Of course only with `<style lang="scss">`.

My App.vue imports the .scss files like this:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import url('@/styles/_default.scss');
...
```

Inside my vue.config.js I have the following lines:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  css: {
        loaderOptions: {
          sass: {
            sassOptions: {
              module: {
                rules: [
                  {
                    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                    use: [
                      // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                      "style-loader",
                      // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                      "css-loader",
                      // Compiles Sass to CSS
                      "sass-loader",
                    ], }, ], }, }, }, },
        },
  })
```

I guess that my vue.config.js is somehow wrong. I tried a lot of other configurations but no one of them has worked so far.
Most of them throw an error while compiling. I also don't quite understand how the config file works but I feel like everything I find on this topic is not up to date anymore :(

Version Infos:

```
"dependencies": {
   "vue": "^3.2.13",
},
"devDependencies": {
   "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
   "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
}
```

Thank you for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import it like this:

```
<style lang="scss" src="@/styles/_default.scss"></style>
```

It works for me

Comment: Not for me tho. It still applies only the css rule. In dev console it is marked as invalid again. It says 'Unknown property name' for '&' to be specific. And everything that follows is invalid

Comment: I did a fresh install of vue which works with your method. And I saw that it was using "sass": "^1.32.7", instead of "node-sass": "^7.0.1". So I changed that as well and now it works ! Thank you!